# Spark RDD - Scala write and Python read

Tags: python, json, scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have a simple Spark Scala script which read bunch of log files and returns an `RDD[Map[String, String]]`

I'm struggling to export a Scala RDD to a pyspark user.

First tried to write a json file using Jackson.

```
val mapper = new ObjectMapper()
mapper.registerModule(DefaultScalaModule)
val rec = sc.textFile("/path/to/log/file.log").

  [ omissis ]

rec.map(f => mapper.writeValueAsString(f))
rec.saveAsTextFile("/path/to/export.json");
```

But when we tried to read the json in pyspark

```
spark.read.json("/path/to/export.json").take(5)
```

An exception is raised

```
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: Reference '11E' is ambiguous, could be: 11E#20457, 11E#20458.;
  at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.plans.logical.LogicalPlan.resolve(LogicalPlan.scala:264)
```

Are there best practices to implement interoperability between Scala and Python in Scala?

What's the more performing way to save an RDD in Scala and reuse it in Python?

The pyspark user very likely would submit sql queries on his side, is this a good way to export the results of my work?

Comment: There a few ways to call scala methods from pySpark. Is this kind of solution can help you? What I mean is, call the scala process via pyspark and get the return from the method as an RDD.

Comment: have you checked out the dataframe API? I think it'd probably be able to solve your problem

Comment: @JamesTobin Yes, but probably I'm to newbie to understand how to use it

Comment: @ThiagoBaldim Well I'm trying to export an list of hashmap, would be wonderful if the counterpart python would read it as they are.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it can help you.

There a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/TRBaldim/2bf67f21bd31ceca3c44f12208a86be6) that allow you to call the Scala code via pyspark. That is a producer of Kafka with kerberos.

See an example of scala code:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD
import org.apache.spark.api.python.SerDeUtil
def fooScala(): JavaRDD[Array[Byte]] = {
    rdd = sc.parallelize(1 to 10)
    SerDeUtil.javaToPython(rdd)
}
```

After that you need to compile your code and generate the jar of your project.

Than in pySpark you can call the class like this:

```
from pyspark.rdd import RDD
_jvm = sc._jvm
python_rdd = _jvm.yourClassPath.fooScala()
```

This process may help you to do what you want.

To call the jar inside the pyspark you have to call via spark-submit like this:

```
spark-submit --master yarn-client --jars ./my-scala-code.jar --driver-class-path ./my-scala-code.jar main.py
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions, I'll give it a try

Comment: How would you access SerDeUtil from within an Object?